# Cells with centered value and background based on value

Tags: java, rendering

here is my problem
I read a DB and show the data via the renderer. Shown data must be centered and bgcolor must change according to the value of the cell.

Following is the renderer. First **table.getColumnModel()** shows the centered value, second one calls a customer renderer to change the color. If I remove the comment on the second call I get the bgcolor but not the centered value and viceversa

```
for (int row = 0; row < table.getColumnCount(); row++) {
    DefaultTableCellRenderer centerRenderer = new DefaultTableCellRenderer();
    centerRenderer.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
    table.getColumnModel().getColumn(row).setCellRenderer(centerRenderer);
    //table.getColumnModel().getColumn(row).setCellRenderer(new CustomRenderer()); 
}
```

This is the Custom renderer

```
class CustomRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer
{
   public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column)
   {
       Component cellComponent = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
       if(table.getValueAt(row, column).equals("A")){
           cellComponent.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
           
       } else if(table.getValueAt(row, column).equals("B")){
           cellComponent.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
       }
       else {cellComponent.setBackground(Color.white);}
           return cellComponent;
     }
}
```

How can I obtain a colored and center cell?
Than you
paps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here a short snippet demonstrating what I think you are trying to achieve:

```
public class Testing {

public static void main(String args[]) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            new Testing();
        }
    });

}

public Testing() {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();

    String[] colNames = { "Col1", "Col2" };
    Object[][] data = { { "A", "B" }, { "B", "C" } };

    JTable table = new JTable(data, colNames);
    CustomRenderer renderer = new CustomRenderer();
    renderer.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
    // table.setDefaultRenderer(String.class, renderer); // if you want to only
    // color and center all strings
    for (int col = 0; col < table.getColumnCount(); col++) {
        // if you want to color and center every entry of the table
        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(col).setCellRenderer(renderer);
    }
    panel.add(table);
    frame.add(panel);

    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

class CustomRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row,
            int column) {
        Component cellComponent = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
        
        cellComponent.setBackground(Color.white); // white if not "A" or "B"
        if (value instanceof String) {
            String temp = (String) value;
            if (temp.equals("A")) {
                cellComponent.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
            } else if (temp.equals("B")) {
                cellComponent.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
            }
        }
        return cellComponent;
    }
}
}
```

The result will look like:

[image]

Note that your custom renderer only has to be created once, not on every loop. The issue in your code was, that you didn't use your own renderer, but a `DefaultTableCellRenderer` instead. Also, if you want to only use the custom rendering on a specific class type, e.g. only on `String` objects, you can use the commented out line instead of iterating through all columns of the table.
And of course you can add further restrictions to the `CustomRenderer` according to your needs.

Comment: Clear and perfect. Thank you